# Javascript variable redundance

Tags: javascript, function, variables, redundancy

I have a simple javascript function like this:

```
function wrapVar (passVar) {
    var option = {
        varValue: passVar,
        hide: true,
        params: { ..otherparams.. }
        };
    return option;
}
```

Eclipse and Aptana validation says that the local variable 'option' is redundant. But the meaning of "redundancy" in this case is not clear to me, what should i do to avoid it?

Comment: not sure you should necessarily avoid that. i think its personal preference and also not something that jshint would pick up.

Comment: Sometimes they hint at redundancy when nothing is wrong with the code itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, it means you can use the equivalent

```js
function wrapVar (passVar) {
    return {
        varValue: passVar,
        hide: true,
        params: { ..otherparams.. }
    };
}
```

Comment: Absolutely true, it was just an optimization tip! the code was already running but i had desire to understand.. Now it's clear, thanks!!